# バリデーションチェック関数が呼び出せていない。

Tags: php

PHPで自動販売機システムを作成しているのですが、
空欄の時にエラーメッセージが表示されるように
バリデーション関数を作成しているのですが、
上手く呼び出せていないみたいです。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
変数の中身を見たところ空でした。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
そして変数をprintしたところ、Array型はString型に変換できない旨のエラーメッセージが表示されました。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
どうすればうまく変数を返し、関数を呼び出せるのでしょうか？
現状ですとやり方がわからないので、
お手数をおかけしますが、ご教授のほどよろしくお願いいたします。

functions.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/tool.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/index.php');
require_once('../../htdocs/mvc/result.php');


function get_db_connect() {
 
if (!$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWD, DB_NAME)) {
        die('error: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($link, DB_CHARACTER_SET);
    return $link;
}

function close_db_connect($link) {

    mysqli_close($link);
}

function insert_drink($link) {
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'POST') {
    return;
}
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'insert') {
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_name = $_POST['new_name'];
                
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === TRUE) {
        
            $new_price = $_POST['new_price'];
                    
        }
        
        if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === TRUE) {
            
            $new_stock = $_POST['new_stock'];
                
            
        }

        /*もしもisset($_POST['new_status']の中身がTRUEならば*/
        if (isset($_POST['new_status']) === TRUE) {
            
            /*もしもisset($_POST['new_stock']の中身がTRUEならば*/
            if ((int) $_POST['new_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['new_status'] === 1) {
                $new_status = (int) $_POST['new_status'];
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください'; 
             }
        } else {
            $err_msg[] = 'ステータスを選択してください';
            
            
        }

            $new_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


            $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_info_table(drink_name, price, created_at, updated_at, status) VALUES(\''.$new_name.'\',\''.$new_price.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_status.'\')';

            if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {

                $drink_id = mysqli_insert_id($link);


                $sql = 'INSERT INTO stock_table(drink_id, stock, created_at, updated_at) VALUES(\''.$drink_id.'\',\''.$new_stock.'\',\''.$new_time.'\',\''.$new_time.'\')';

                if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
                    $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                    
            
                }
            } else {
                $err_msg[] = 'drink_info_tableへのデータの登録に失敗しました';
                
                
            }
                $complete_msg[] = '追加登録完了!';
                
            }
}

        
// function update_drink() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'update') {

//         if (isset($_POST['update_stock']) === TRUE) {
//             if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['update_stock'])) === 1) {
//                 $update_stock = (int) cut($_POST['update_stock']);

//                 $update_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $update_id = $_POST['drink_id'];

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $update_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $update_time;

//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                     $complete_msg[] = '在庫数更新完了!';
                    
//                     ;
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = '在庫数の更新に失敗しました';
                    
                   
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = '0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                
              
//             }
//         }
//     }
// }
// function change_drink() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && $_POST['sql_kind'] === 'change') {

//         if (isset($_POST['change_status']) === TRUE) {
//             if ((int) $_POST['change_status'] === 0 || (int) $_POST['change_status'] === 1) {
//                 $change_id = $_POST['drink_id'];
//                 $change_status = (int) $_POST['change_status'];

//                 $change_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//                 $sql = 'UPDATE drink_info_table SET updated_at = \'' . $change_time . '\', status = ' . $change_status . ' WHERE drink_id = ' . $change_id;


//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) === TRUE) {
//                     $complete_msg[] = 'ステータス変更完了!';
                    
//                 } else {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'ステータスの変更に失敗しました';
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'ステータスは公開か非公開を選択してください';
//             }
//         }
//     }

//     if (count($err_msg) === 0) {
        
//         mysqli_commit($link);
//     } else {
        
//         mysqli_rollback($link);
//     }

//     $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, stock_table.stock, drink_info_table.status, FROM drink_info_table LEFT JOIN stock_table ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    
//     if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//             $data[] = $row;
//         }
//     } else {
//         $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
//     }
// }



function do_sql($link) {
    $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_id, drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price, drink_info_table.status,stock_table.stock
    FROM drink_info_table
    JOIN stock_table
    ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id';
    $data = [];
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
    } else {
        $err_msg[] = 'データの抽出に失敗しました';
    }
    return $data;
}

// function id_check() {
//     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

//         $purchase_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

//         if (isset($_POST['drink_id']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['drink_id'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからdrink_idを受信できませんでした';
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $drink_id = (int) $_POST['drink_id'];
//                     break;
//             }
//         } else {
//             $err_msg[] = '商品を選択してください';
//         }

//         if (isset($_POST['money']) === TRUE) {

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === ''):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($_POST['money'] === NULL):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'index.phpからmoneyを受信できませんでした';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', cut($_POST['money'])) !== 1):
//                     $err_msg[] = '金額は0以上の半角整数を入力してください';
                    
//                     break;
//                 default:
//                     $money = (int) cut($_POST['money']);
//                     break;
//             }
//         }

//         if (count($err_msg) === 0) {

//             $sql = 'SELECT drink_info_table.drink_name, drink_info_table.price,  drink_info_table.status, stock_table.stock
//             FROM drink_info_table
//             JOIN stock_table
//             ON drink_info_table.drink_id = stock_table.drink_id
//             WHERE drink_info_table.drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
//                     $data[] = $row;
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = '情報の取得に失敗しました';
//             }

//             foreach ($data as $info) {

//                 $drink_name = $info['drink_name'];
//                 $price = (int) $info['price'];
//                 $stock = (int) $info['stock'];
//                 $status = (int) $info['status'];

//                 $remaining_stock = $stock - 1;
//                 $return = $money - $price;
//             }

//             switch (TRUE) {
//                 case ($return < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'お金が足りません';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($remaining_stock < 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は品切れです';
                    
//                     break;
//                 case ($status === 0):
//                     $err_msg[] = 'この商品は選択できません';
                    
//                     break;
//             }

//             $sql = 'UPDATE stock_table SET stock = ' . $remaining_stock . ', updated_at = \'' . $purchase_time . '\' WHERE drink_id = ' . $drink_id;

//             if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {

//                 $sql = 'INSERT INTO drink_history_table(drink_id, purchased_at) VALUES (' . $drink_id . ', \'' . $purchase_time . '\')';

//                 if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql) !== TRUE) {
//                     $err_msg[] = 'drink_history_tableへの追加に失敗しました';
                    
//                 }
//             } else {
//                 $err_msg[] = 'stock_tableの更新に失敗しました';
//         }
        
//     }
// }

// function html_enc($text){ 
// return htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
// }
// }

function validation_check($link) {
   $err_msg = [];
   if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === "") {
     $err_msg = '商品名を入力してください。';
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['new_price']) === "") {
     $err_msg = '値段を入力してください';
    }
    
    if (isset($_POST['new_stock']) === "") {
     $err_msg = '個数を入力してください';
    }
    return $err_msg;

}
```

tool.php

```
<?php
require_once('../../include/model/functions.php');
require_once('../../include/conf/const.php');
$link = get_db_connect();
$data = insert_drink($link);
$data = do_sql($link);
require_once('../../include/view/tool2.php');

$data =  [
                'drink_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'created_at' => '',
                'updated_at' => '',
                'status' => '',
            ];

close_db_connect($link);
```

tool2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>自動販売機商品管理</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php require_once('../../include/model/functions.php'); ?>
    <?php
    $complete_msg = insert_drink($link);
    if (count($complete_msg) !== 0) {
        foreach ($complete_msg as $complete) { ?>
            <p><?php print $complete; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>
    <?php 
    validation_check($link);
    if (count($err_msg) !== 0)  {
        foreach ($err_msg as $err) { ?>
            <p><?php print $err; ?></p>
    <?php }
    } ?>

    <h1>自動販売機管理ツール</h1>

    <section>
        <h2>新規商品追加</h2>

        <form action="tool.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label>名前: <input type="text" name="new_name" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>値段: <input type="text" name="new_price" size="30" /></label><br>
            <label>個数: <input type="text" name="new_stock" size="30" /></label><br>
            <select name="new_status"><br>
                <option value="0">非公開</option>
                <option value="1">公開</option>
                <option value="2">入力チェック用</option>
            </select><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="insert">
            <input type="submit" value="■□■□商品追加■□■□" />
        </form>

    </section>

    <section>
        <h2>商品情報変更</h2>
        <table>
            <caption>商品一覧</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>商品名</th>
                    <th>価格</th>
                    <th>在庫数</th>
                    <th>ステータス</th>
                </tr>

                <?php if (empty($data) !== TRUE) {
                    foreach ($data as $list) {
                        if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                            <tr class="status_0">
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <? php print htmlspecialchars($list,ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'); ?>
                            <td class="d_name"><?php print $list['drink_name']; ?></td>
                            <td class="d_price"><?php print $list['price']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="text" class="input_text_width text_align_right" name="update_stock" value="<?php print $list['stock']; ?>">個
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="変更">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="update">
                                </form>
                            </td>

                            <?php if ((int) $list['status'] === 0) { ?>
                                <td class="d_status">
                                    <form method="post">
                                        <input type="submit" value="非公開 → 公開">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="1">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                    </form>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <td class="d_status">
                                <form method="post">
                                    <input type="submit" value="公開 → 非公開">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="change_status" value="0">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="drink_id" value="<?php print $list['drink_id']; ?>">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="sql_kind" value="change">
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                <?php }
                        }
                    } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

const.php

```
<?php
$err_msg = [];
$complete_msg = [];

define('DB_HOST',   'localhost'); // データベースのホスト名又はIPアドレス
define('DB_USER',   '');  // MySQLのユーザ名
define('DB_PASSWD', '');    // MySQLのパスワード
define('DB_NAME',   '');    // データベース名

define('HTML_CHARACTER_SET', 'UTF-8');  // HTML文字エンコーディング
define('DB_CHARACTER_SET',   'UTF8');   // DB文字エンコーディング

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Comment: 重複候補: [returnしたデータの格納方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/80837)

Answer (score 1):

まず前提として関数は呼び出せていますし、あなたが書いたとおりにプログラムは動いています。きちんと値も返しています。問題は関数の作りが良くないです。
大きく分けて２つの問題点があります。

（１）issetの使いかたとifの条件の書き方

issetの使い方があっていないです。
まずは[マニュアル](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.isset.php)を確認してみましょう。

```
if (isset($_POST['new_name']) === "") {
```

この書き方ですとissetの返り値が空白文字になればエラーと判定するという条件ですが、issetはかならずtrueとfalseを返すため絶対この条件には入りません。

存在するかどうかのチェックはシンプルにissetを利用しましょう

```
if (!isset($_POST['new_name'])) {
```

もし空白文字かどうかをチェックしたいのであればissetを使わず単純に空白文字かどうかチェックしましょう

```
if ($_POST['new_name'] === "") {
```

なにをチェックしたいかで条件が変わります。
おそらく今回は
「存在しない場合または存在するかつ空白の場合」

```
if (!isset($_POST['new_name']) || (isset($_POST['new_name']) && $_POST['new_name'] === "") ) {
```

なのでこういう条件を書くとよいでしょう。
まずは頭の中で条件を書いてみてくださいそれに沿ってプログラムを作成してみてください。

(2)$err_msgの配列の使い方と追加の仕方
本文中では配列で宣言しているのにエラーメッセージを入れるところではstringの代入の仕方をしています。

```
$err_msg = [];
$err_msg = '商品名を入力してください。';
```

配列として使いたいのであれば、ソースコードでコメントアウトしているところのように（例えばfunction.phpの193行目とか）記述しましょう。
おそらくコピペミスか、コードの写しミスかなとおもいます。この辺りはよく注意しましょう。

```
$err_msg = [];
$err_msg[] = '商品名を入力してください。';
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。